# Python find first occurrence of character after index

Tags: python

I am trying to get the index of the first occurrence of a character that occurs in a string *after* a specified index. For example:

```
string = 'This + is + a + string'

# The 'i' in 'is' is at the 7th index, find the next occurrence of '+'
string.find_after_index(7, '+')

# Return 10, the index of the next '+' character
>>> 10
```

Comment: See: https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/stdtypes.html#str.find

Answer (score 45, accepted):

Python is so predicable:

```
>>> string = 'This + is + a + string'
>>> string.find('+',7)
10
```

Checkout `help(str.find)`:

```
find(...)
    S.find(sub[, start[, end]]) -> int

    Return the lowest index in S where substring sub is found,
    such that sub is contained within S[start:end].  Optional
    arguments start and end are interpreted as in slice notation.

    Return -1 on failure.
```

Also works with `str.index` except that this will `raise ValueError` instead of `-1` when the substring is not found.

Comment: Note the syntax is also very similar for `list.index` although it wasn't documented until recently http://bugs.python.org/issue28587

Comment: I shed a tear after reading this. Python is beautiful. I didn't realize that find took additional arguments.

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
start_index = 7
next_index = string.index('+', start_index)
```

Comment: Why would you do it like this instead of passing `start_index` to `index()`?

Comment: Because my Python is rusty :)

Updated it with your suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

```
string.find('+', 7)
```

Read [the documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#string-methods).

Answer (score 0):

```
In [1]: str.index?
Docstring:
S.index(sub[, start[, end]]) -> int

Like S.find() but raise ValueError when the substring is not found.
Type:      method_descriptor

In [2]: string = 'This + is + a + string'

In [3]: string.index('+', 7)
Out[3]: 10
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for i in range(index, len(string)):
    if string[i] == char:
         print(i)
```

The above code will loop through from the index you provide `index` to the length of the string `len(string)`. Then if the index of the string is equal to the character, `char`, that you are looking for then it will print the index.

You could put this in a function and pass in the, string, index and character and then return i.